# Merging CountVectorizer in Scikit-Learn feature extraction

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-extraction

I am new to scikit-learn and needed some help with something that I have been working on.

I am trying to classify two types of documents (say, type A and type B) using Multinomial Naive Bayes classification. In order to get the term counts for these documents, I am using the CountVectorizer class in sklearn.feature_extraction.text.

The problem is that the two types of documents require different regular expressions to extract tokens (token_pattern parameter to CountVectorization). I can't seem to find a way to first load the training documents of type A and then of type B. Is it possible to do something like:

```
vecA = CountVectorizer(token_pattern="[a-zA-Z]+", ...)
vecA.fit(list_of_type_A_document_content)
...
vecB = CountVectorizer(token_pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+", ...)
vecB.fit(list_of_type_B_document_content)
...
# Somehow merge the two vectorizers results and get the final sparse matrix
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

```
vecA = CountVectorizer(token_pattern="[a-zA-Z]+", ...)
vecA.fit_transform(list_of_type_A_document_content)
vecB = CountVectorizer(token_pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+", ...)
vecB.fit_transform(list_of_type_B_document_content)
combined_features = FeatureUnion([('CountVectorizer', vectA),('CountVect', vectB)])
combined_features.transform(test_data)
```

You can read more about FeatureUnion from
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html

which is available from version 0.13.1

Comment: If both 'vectA' and 'vectB' contains word 'happy', then feature would be 'vectA_name_happy' and 'vectB_name_happy'. Probably not what expected. A single feature 'happy' is needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
vecA = CountVectorizer(token_pattern="[a-zA-Z]+", ...)
vecA.fit_transform(list_of_type_A_document_content)
vecB = CountVectorizer(token_pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]+", ...)
vecB.fit_transform(list_of_type_B_document_content)
```

And you can merge the sparse matrices:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, hstack

combined_features= hstack([vecA, vecB], 'csr')
```