# I get isnan error when I merge two countvectorizers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, text-classification, countvectorizer

I'm going dialect text classification and I have this code:

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizerN = CountVectorizer(analyzer='char',ngram_range=(3,4))
XN = vectorizerN.fit_transform(X_train)

vectorizerMX = CountVectorizer(vocabulary=a['vocabs'])
MX = vectorizerMX.fit_transform(X_train)

from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
combined_features = FeatureUnion([('CountVectorizer', MX),('CountVect', XN)])
combined_features.transform(test_data)
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I was following the code in this post:
[Merging CountVectorizer in Scikit-Learn feature extraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37081597/merging-countvectorizer-in-scikit-learn-feature-extraction?rq=1)

**Also, how can I train and predict afterwards?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should union `vectorizerN` and `vectorizerMX`, not `MX` and `XN`.
Change the line to

```
combined_features = FeatureUnion([('CountVectorizer', vectorizerMX), ('CountVect', vectorizerN)])
```

Comment: and then I do combined_features.fit_transform(X_train)? why did he do it before combining though?

Comment: The two vectorizers are fitted on the `X_train`. You want the `test_data` to be mapped to the union of the vectorizer. That's why you have to do `combined_features.transform(test_data)`. Am I missing something with your question?